# I can't deploy angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, firebase-cli

I am having trouble deploying an application.

Firebase cli cannot display the list of projects and I get the following error:

and in the **firebase-debug.log** file it prints the following information:

Another problem is an error in the terminal:

```
(node:16028) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FirebaseError: Failed to make request to https://firebase-public.firebaseio.com/cli.json
    at Client.<anonymous> (npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\apiv2.js:168:23)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (C:\Users\marenas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\apiv2.js:6:65)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:16028) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an 
async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16028) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have already tried to install the firebase tools, also try to close session and reopen it, try the login with tokens that is **firebase login:ci** and I cannot list the projects with the command **firebase projects:list**.

Comment: It seems like the CLI is trying to load some configuration data from https://firebase-public.firebaseio.com/cli.json, and can't reach it. Can you check if you can open that URL in a browser (it loads without problems for me)?

Comment: Correctly, the URL is opened success.

Comment: Hmmm... that is interesting. If you can open it in a browser, I have no idea why the CLI isn't able to open it. If you can reproduce the problem, it might be worth posting on the firebase-tools repo on Github, or [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have to use a proxy so I can access firebaseio.com.
But it seems that the CLI have some bug so it can't use the proxy.
So I use Proxifier work with my socks proxy as a Transparent proxy.
Done!

Comment: I already found the problem, the antivirus was blocking me some sources through the terminal.

Thank you.

Comment: In my case, the network was a proxy network. i used "proxyCap" to resolve this.